# Requring assistance with a password dialog box Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to make a password dialog box which tells you to input a password then once entered displays a alert dialog box saying you entered and displays your password in asterisks and also in normal text. I have that bit but need it to prevent me from entering a password if my password contains spaces. For example Bill Gates shouldn't work. Can someone please help this is what I have so far.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Password Alert Box</title>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
//declared variables
var input1 = 0;

input1=prompt("Please enter your Password here","Enter Password Here");//made a prompt box to enter the password
var asterisks = (new Array(input1.length+1).join("*"));//converts the password string into asterisks
window.alert("Valid password "+ asterisks + "\n You entered the password " + input1); //outputs the message valid password, along with the string entered in asterisks, also outputs the password in plain text
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to input spaces and inform him afterwards that he has entered an invalid character or do you want to prevent spaces as he's typing? The latter wouldn't be possible with `prompt()`.

Comment: I want the user to not be able to input spaces. So it tells him " invalid it contains a space"

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function psw() {
    var input1 = prompt("Please enter your Password here","Enter Password Here");

    if(input1.indexOf(" ") > 0) {
        alert('error can not contain spaces');
        psw();
        return false;
    }

    var asterisks = (new Array(input1.length+1).join("*"));

    alert("Valid password "+ asterisks + "\n You entered the password " + input1);
}

psw();
```

notice: I used *indexOf* which working with IE9+

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52fvhkzp/)

Comment: @Tom np, you are wellcome, if answer solve your problem then mark it

Answer (score 0):

A dialog box. If you are using passwords, I would refrain from using prompts since it is not as secure as `'<input type="password" />'`. This means you won't be able to use prompt. Consider the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="display: none;" id="alert">
    <form>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password here" />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var pass = document.getElementById('password');
pass.onkeyup = function (e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (key == 32) {
        //spacebar -- so lets clear what has currently been written
        this.value = "";
        alert('Spaces are not allowed, please try again');
    }
}
document.getElementById('show').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'block';
}

document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(pass.value + ' ... ' + (new Array(pass.value.length + 1).join("*")));
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#alert {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Here we create a "floating" box ( similar in a way to dialogue boxes/modals in jQuery). Inside this box you'll find the input type password I was talking about earlier within a form.

For your case, you don't need to send the form off to a php file for it to be handled, so you just intercept the form and show the password's value within an alert.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/qLqmt586/4/)

update, it is possible to intercept the spacebar before the password's value is changed and just not do anything. For example, you could use the `onkeyup` event and copy the same code. IF a spacebar is detected all you need to do is `e.preventDefault();` and the spacebar will not be added to your password's value.

[DEMO2 where spacebar is just not added to the password](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/qLqmt586/5/)